# Add number to transform attribute

Tags: d3.js

**jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/xgt8Loxb/4

I am trying to zoom, but when zoom starts it's translating coordinates became 0,0 and I can't find a way to add offset.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate (" + d3.event.transform.x + "," + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")")
        }))
        .select("g")
```

I tried to add to do `("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + 640 "," + d3.event.transform.y + 360 + ")")`
But it just keeps concatenating, despite parseInt() or anhything else, honestly. I tried everything, so I guess it's impossible to add a number to dynamic attribute in d3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't apply the transform to the whole SVG on the zoom function. Apply it just to the group instead:

```
.on("zoom", function() {
    g.attr("transform", "translate (" + d3.event.transform.x +
        "," + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")")
});
```

Second, use `zoom.transform` to preserve the original "translate":

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate((width / 2), (height / 2)))
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kx7vdxzq/

PS: regarding the *title* of your question, since you are concatenating strings and numbers, you should set the numbers first. This can be done with a simple parenthesis:

```
("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.transform.x + 640) + 
    "," + (d3.event.transform.y + 360) + ")")
```